# Creating Folders in salesforce

Tags: apex

I need to create a Folder With Name Email Files in order to avoid the error.But I cannot find where to create a folder.This is not a Report Folder.It is a document Folder

```
 Folder DocId=[Select Id from Folder where Name='Email Files' or Name='Email Files'];
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new Document Folder, navigate to the Documents Tab and click the Create New Folder Link.

[image]

For a new Email Template folder, Setup > Communication Templates and hit the Create New Folder Link